# Why isn't the Image Editor showing the denoising image like in the Compositor?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, denoise

I am fiddling with denoising a set of images but the image in the Image Editor is not denoised as in the Composition Tab. Is there something that I am missing to do?

I have already tried detaching and reattaching the nodes whilst also reloading the Image Editor.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to switch on top row of *Image Editor* from your *0001.png* to **Viewer Node** :)

[image]